# How to make SSMS Properties Window coincide with object selected in Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

The Properties Window in SSMS seems lame to me. All it shows is the current connection properties. I would like to be able to click on an object in the Object Explorer (e.g. a table or a column) and instantly see the corresponding properties displayed in the Properties Window. Is there some setting in Options that would make this possible?

Now, if I switch to a database diagram and select a box (Table) or field (Column), the Properties Window updates accordingly. But I rarely interact with DB diagrams. I want this functionality while I am working in the Query Designer. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing out of the box that will let you do this.

This is kind of confusing... because the Properties window never shows properties about *anything* in Object Explorer. If you right-click | Properties on anything in Object Explorer, you always get a pop-up dialog box. The Properties window only shows properties for objects that appear in select MDI-style windows, such as query windows.

Having said that, even though there's no way to do this, I'm not even sure it's such a good idea.

In order to return that kind of information to the UI, SSMS has to hit the server with a metadata query. SSMS is a data-driven application; it's just special in that it operates on SQL Server itself. IntelliSense works the same way. If you're on a production server, you probably don't want this kind of thing enabled because every time you touch a different node in Object Explorer (which is very frequently), it will have to hit the server to retrieve the data. And then you get into a debate about how to turn it off, and ......

Comment: some good points. thanks. (I still wish it was at least an option -- especially while working on a dev server. It would be super useful for getting aquainted with a new database.)

Comment: I think kmote may have been thinking of something more along the lines of some functionality that i know of that exists in Oracle SQL Developer. In Oracle SQL Developer, if you highlight an object name, such as a table name, function, or procedure, and press SHIFT+F4, you are presented with a popup of the objects properties. This saves the effort of navigating the object tree. Unfortunately i'm not aware of similar functionality in SMSS.

Comment: @msMask: There are dedicated Properties windows for most objects in SSMS, as I mentioned. What's under discussion is populating that same information in a context-sensitive way within one of the main UI windows.